# Include from higher level than root

Tags: php, include, root

**What I have:**

MAIN_domain.sth -> "ROOT"

domain1.sth -> *"ROOT/DOMAIN1"*
domain2.sth -> *"ROOT/DOMAIN2"*

**What I need:**

I need to include *"ROOT/GENERAL/file.php"* into a script running on domainx.sth

**What I tried:**

```
include('../GENERAL/file.php'); //In a script running on domain1.sth
```

**Problem:**

PHP won't let me *"walk out"* from the current ROOT, on *DOMAIN1* or *DOMAIN2*.

**Notes:**

- I've been researching, but I didn't found this particular problem
  anywhere. And I must be searching it wrong cause it seems a very
  normal thing.
- I Know about the existence of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but I don't
  know how to implement it here.

Thanks a lot for reading. Have a wonderful **to-day**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next code

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../GENERAL/file.php';
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. It doesn't include the file. I tried "file_exists()" and it returns **false**. I don't understand why, cause the file DOES exist. What could the problem be? Thanks.

Comment: try to check value of  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. echo  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. It's now working with `dirname()`. Thanks for your wonderful help! Thanks for your time too!  :)